# Django forms not sh

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

For some reason, my forms.py doesn't view any of the fields, instead, it only shows the 'Add' button and I don't know what to do anymore. I'd really appreciate if someone who knows what they're doing could tell me what I did, or didn't do.

Please note that I'm new to Django, thank you.

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Measurement
from .forms import MeasurementForm
from django.views import generic


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Measurement
    context_object_name = 'measurement_list'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    queryset = Measurement.objects.all()


def new_measurement(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MeasurementForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.measurement_date = timezone.now()
            measurement.save()
    else:
        form = MeasurementForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

forms.py:
    from django import forms
    from .models import Measurement

```
class MeasurementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Measurement
        fields = ('measurement_value', 'measurement_unit')
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Climate Measurement Tool</h1>

    <h2>Add a new measurement</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save">Add</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Measurements</h2>
    {% if measurement_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for measurement in measurement_list %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ measurement }}</p>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No measurements yet</p>
    {% endif %}    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new_measurement()` view correctly initializes a form instance and passes it to the template.

Unfortunately, that view is never called.

`urls.py` defines only one url, handled by `IndexView.as_view()`, which does not pass a form instance to the template.

Comment: Oh, you're right, thank you! Would you mind explaining to me how I could do what I'm trying to do? I tried to add new measurement() inside the IndexView, but it didn't work out. This is probably a very beginner-ish question, but I'm still a bit confused by forms and haven't found any good Django 2.0 tutorials that explain these concepts so that one could apply them.